# Unexpected behavior in tf.data.Dataset map function

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am working on a problem where I need to apply some transformation to my dataset using the map function that tf.data.Dataset provides. The idea is to apply this transformation that rely on some random number and then chain this transformation with another function.

The idea is something like that:

```py
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]) 
dataset = dataset.map(lambda x: x + tf.random.uniform([], minval=0, maxval=9, dtype=tf.dtypes.int32)) #map function is done once
```

I thought that if I print `dataset` twice I should expect the same values, however, the result is the following.

```py
ds = dataset.zip((dataset,dataset))
print(list(ds.as_numpy_iterator()))
#output -> [(8, 2), (2, 1), (8, 9), (2, 2), (6, 7), (2, 2)]
```

Any clues on how can I get exactly the same values after a *.map* transformation which relies on random numbers?
It seems that the map function is done **twice** instead of once as I declared in the code snippet.

P.D: Using a random seed does the trick but its just hidding the problem.

**[EDITED]**

What I need is to perform an operation like this:

```py
ds = tf.data.Dataset.range(1, 10)
y = ds.map(lambda x: my_random_operation(x))
x = ds.map(lambda x: another_random_operation(x))
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((x, y))
```

As you can see, *x* depends on *y*, and it doesn't seem that this behavior is happening. That's why I asked how to apply the random operation *first* and then apply the map to illustrate this.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to set a random seed to get deterministic behavior, because when zipping the two datasets, they will be called [internally](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/3f878cff5b698b82eea85db2b60d65a2e320850e/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py#L4606) (similar to the python `zip` function) triggering the map function:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.random.set_seed(111)
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]) 
dataset = dataset.map(lambda x: x + tf.random.uniform([], minval=0, maxval=9, dtype=tf.dtypes.int32))

ds = dataset.zip((dataset, dataset))
print(list(ds.as_numpy_iterator()))
# [(7, 7), (8, 8), (8, 8), (2, 2), (8, 8), (6, 6)]
```

**Update 1**

Maybe something like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

ds = tf.data.Dataset.range(1, 10)
def my_random_operation(x):
  # Or with stateless uniform
  return x + tf.random.uniform([], minval=0, maxval=9, dtype=tf.dtypes.int64, seed=1)

def another_random_operation(x):
  # Or with stateless uniform
  return x + tf.random.uniform([], minval=0, maxval=9, dtype=tf.dtypes.int64, seed=2)
  
y = ds.map(lambda x: my_random_operation(x))
x = ds.map(lambda x: another_random_operation(x))
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((x, y))

print(list(dataset.as_numpy_iterator()))
```

What could also work is something like `np.random.randint` which would also be executed only once, since it won't be traced in a `tf.Graph`:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

ds = tf.data.Dataset.range(1, 10)
def my_random_operation(x):
  return x + np.random.randint(0, 9)

def another_random_operation(x):
  return x + np.random.randint(0, 9)
  
y = ds.map(lambda x: my_random_operation(x))
x = ds.map(lambda x: another_random_operation(x))
```

**Update 2**

Regarding the reason behind this behavior, notice that the variable `num_traces` is called 18 times altogether, which corresponds to your 9 tuples:

```
import tensorflow as tf

ds = tf.data.Dataset.range(1, 10)

num_traces = tf.Variable(0)

def my_random_operation(x):
  global num_traces
  num_traces.assign_add(1)
  return x + tf.random.uniform([], minval=0, maxval=9, dtype=tf.dtypes.int64)

ds = ds.map(lambda x: my_random_operation(x))
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((ds, ds))

print(list(dataset.as_numpy_iterator()))
print(num_traces)
# [(2, 3), (9, 8), (7, 7), (11, 11), (8, 9), (14, 11), (13, 11), (14, 16), (12, 16)]
# <tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=() dtype=int32, numpy=18>
```

This behavior is in accordance with the information in the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/random_numbers#interaction_with_tffunction):

> When used as an argument to a tf.function, different generator objects
> will cause retracing of the tf.function.

So one assumption is that retracing is triggered by trying to zip the datasets after the first execution of `dataset.map`. The datasets, as mentioned previously, are iterated internally and therefore trigger the map function again because the values have changed since the first `map` call. Check this [thread](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/3f878cff5b698b82eea85db2b60d65a2e320850e/tensorflow/python/ops) also.

Comment: Thanks for the response! But even setting a random seed does the trick does not resolve what I am asking for.

Comment: @ÀlexEncaladoMasià Can you show what your desired result would be?

Comment: The desired output is exactly what you post after your first update, but without using a random seed.
I expect to get the same result without using a random seed because first you apply the mapping transformation (just one time) then you zip the dataset with itself. So you shouldn't need to use a random seed.

Comment: have you tried removing `tf.random.set_seed(222)` and just using a seed in `tf.random.uniform`? See updated answer.

Comment: I have tried, and does the trick. But my question is why without using a random seed the result is still being different? I mean, you **first** perform the random operation, you **then** zip the dataset with itself (which in this case is like copying the dataset). So why the numbers are different?

Comment: See updated answer @ÀlexEncaladoMasià. Understandable?

Comment: Thank you! Now I understand why the results are different.

Answer (score 0):

I think it makes a lot more sense to create separate datasets, zip them, and *then* perform a common operation.

```
import tensorflow as tf

ds1 = tf.data.Dataset.range(1, 4)
ds2 = tf.data.Dataset.range(4, 8)

ds = tf.data.Dataset.zip((ds1, ds2))

# [(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]


def add_random_number(a, b):
    random_number = tf.random.uniform([], minval=0, maxval=9, dtype=tf.dtypes.int64)
    return a + random_number, b + random_number


ds = ds.map(add_random_number)

print(list(ds.as_numpy_iterator()))

# [(7, 10), (3, 6), (10, 13)] +6, +1, +7
```

Comment: The thing is that I need to perform this random operation first (only once) and then chain another map function to the result of the previous operation. Finally I will use both datasets. I edited my question for a better understanding of the problem